# What are the key points to avoid table locks?

Tags: mysql, optimization

MySQL is using at my company and most of the database administration works on trying to solve the table locks. What are the key points to avoid table locks(I mean at database side and even at software -Java-)

Comment: Do you mean a) deadlocks or b) excessive time waiting for a lock?

Comment: @Gaius they are deadlocks.

Comment: You'd better search the site for deadlocks: [Deadlocks on DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=deadlocks). There are plenty questions and suggestions about how to handle them.

Answer (score 3):

First a quick recap on what a deadlock is. Let's say you have two sessions, 1 and 2, and two resources, A and B. The following sequence then occurs:

1. Session 1 gets a lock on resource A
2. Session 2 gets a lock on resource B
3. Session 1 requests a lock on resource B, but has to wait until session 2 has released it. We are fine up until this point
4. Session 2 requests a lock on resource A - but session 1 is blocked and can never go forwards to release it. Deadlock occurs.

There is only a very limited amount your DBA can do about this because this situation originates *in the application*, it merely manifests itself in the database. It is best to adopt a convention of always locking resource in the same order. If we had the convention of always locking in the order A, B then our scenario would be:

1. Session 1 gets a lock on resource A
2. Session 2 requests a lock on A, but has to wait for session 1
3. Session 1 gets a lock on resource B, completes its work, and releases both
4. Session 2 gets locks on both A and B, completes its work, and releases both. No deadlocks.

Comment: Also try to keep your transactions as short as possible.  If you have slow running queries, tune them up!

Comment: That will manifest itself as time spent waiting for a lock - not as a deadlock

Answer (score 2):

You can also change your lock granularity by changing your MYSQL DB engine. InnoDB gives your row level locking which is finer when compared to MyISAM's table level locking.